# Is it good for performance to use MATH in Order By?

Tags: mysql, math, select, sql-order-by

I've one question only: Suppose we have a table (activity_feed) with 1.000.000 row, a table (activity_feed_per_user) with a relation between the user who request the feed and the activity that he will see and tables whit some stats from the activity that all be fatched by the app.

If i have to order the result by a rank (that depends even by time, so is variable every second), is this query good to use? Or is not at all?

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT feed.activity_id, feed.body, counter.comments, counter.likes, user.username,
(0.25 * (
        (1 / TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,feed.datetime,now()) ) +
        ( 1 - (1 / (((comments + 1)* 1) + ((likes + 1) * 0.5))) ) +
        activity_type.peso +
        user_affinity.affinity
    )) as ranking
FROM activity_feed_per_user as feed_user
INNER JOIN activity_feed as feed ON feed_user.activity_id = feed.activity_id
INNER JOIN activity_type ON feed.activity_type = activity_type.activity_type_id
INNER JOIN activity_social_counter as counter ON feed_user.activity_id = counter.activity_id
INNER JOIN user_info as user ON user.user_id = feed.user_id
INNER JOIN user_affinity ON feed.user_id = user_affinity.user_related AND user_affinity.user_id = '1'
WHERE feed_user.user_id = '1' 
ORDER BY ranking DESC
```

This is the explain

```
1 | SIMPLE | user_affinity | ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | const | 2 | 100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesor
1 | SIMPLE | user | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 |db.user_affinity.user_related | 1 | 100.00
1 | SIMPLE | feed_user | ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | const | 9 | 100.00 | Using index
1 | SIMPLE | feed | eq_refvPRIMARY,activity_type,user_idvPRIMARY | 4 | db.feed_user.activity_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using where
1 | SIMPLE | activity_type | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 1 | db.feed.activity_type | 1 | 100.00
1 | SIMPLE | counter | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | db.feed_user.activity_id | 1 | 100.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` in your query will force a "Using filesort" operation, and that can be an expensive operation on large result sets.  (MySQL can sometimes satisfy an ORDER BY using an index, avoiding a "Using filesort" operation; but in your case, the expression ("math") will need to evaluated for all rows in the result set.

If it's returning the resultset you need, then your query looks good.

Comment: Another problem would be (i think) that app request LIMITED results (es. LIMIT 0,10 - then - LIMIT 11, 20) and this, probably, will force the query to make this expensive work a lot of time (for every user)

Comment: @Monte: very good point. To get "only" the first 10 rows, the query is going to have to do a sort operation. A subsequent query to get "only" the the next 10 rows will have to perform the sort operation again. If this query is going to be run frequently, then implementing a cache layer may be appropriate.

Comment: The problem with caching this type of query is that for the 2/4, the ranking, change every second (and for every user). My god!

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` on a value that has no index has to look at every row the query produces, so what you propose can hurt performance for queries that return huge result sets.

Comment: I know it, but i cant see better solution. The only thing that i can do is to remove the ranking and sort result by ID DESC. But it's not a solution...

Comment: If you need the result sorted it is going to take time to sort it, whether you do it in the database or in your code. There's no way around it.

Comment: That's true. In this way is even hard to cache the results, with memcache. At this point, the only things to do, is to test this query and, if it will not work good, remove the ranking and order by ids.